# React.js Handling Events Browser Missing

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, event-handling

I am starting to learn React.js by watching some tutorials and documentation. Some how I am having this problem on Google Chrome:

[image]

And in Firefox it does not show anything and was suposed to show the information from the code.

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<!-- jQuery, jQuery.ui -->
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<!-- Bootstrap -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<!-- React -->
<script src="https://fbcdn-dragon-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t39.3284-6/11057025_805715566176382_77439371_n.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.29/browser.js"></script>

<!--Custom Styles -->
<link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<title>React Bulletin Board</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="react-container"></div>
<script src="js/Note.js" type="text/babel" ></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var Note = React.createClass({

    edit: function() {

        alert('editing note');

    },

    remove: function() {

        alert('removing note');

    },

    render: function() {

        return (

            <div className="note">

                <span>

                    <button className="btn btn-primary glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"/>
                    <button className="btn btn-danger glyphicon glyphicon-trash"/>

                </span>

            </div>

        );

    }

});

React.render(<Note>Hello World</Note>, 
    document.getElementById('react-container'));
```

**CSS**

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Shadows+Into+Light);

body,
html,
div.board,
div#react-container {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

div.board {
    background-color: brown;
    width: 100%;
    background: #eab92d;
    background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #eab92d 57%, #c79810 99%);
    background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(57%, #eab92d), color-stop(99%, #c79810));
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #eab92d 57%, #c79810 99%);
    background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #eab92d 57%, #c79810 99%);
    background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, #eab92d 57%, #c79810 99%);
    background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #eab92d 57%, #c79810 99%);
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#eab92d', endColorstr='#c79810', GradientType=1);

}

div.note {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    background-color: yellow;
    margin: 2px 0;
    position: relative;
    cursor: -webkit-grab;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, .2);
}

div.note:active {
    cursor: -webkit-grabbing;
}

div.note p {
    font-size: 22px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-family: "Shadows Into Light", Arial;
}

div.note:hover > span {
    opacity: 1;
}

div.note > span {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 2px;
    right: 2px;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: opacity .25s linear;
}

div.note button {
    margin: 2px;
}

div.note > textarea {
    height: 75%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

.glyphicon-plus {
    position: fixed;
    top: 10px;
    right: 10px;
}
```

I do not understand why I have missing information in both browsers. The information should apear since this is a part of a tutorial code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a Cross Origin issue. You are probably trying to load Note.js from your local drive using either file:// or C:\. To use Cross Origin requests, you would need to install a web server on your computer. Look into express.js and this example on how to setup a simple node.js web server on your machine: https://expressjs.com/en/starter/hello-world.html